# How to update the div in the respective td in a table which is created by clone method

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have created a dynamic table using the clone method.
I have placed a search box and a div in each td of my table.

Now on selection of the item from the search box, I am trying to display in selected value in the div present in the same cell. It is working for the first cell. But not for the other dynamically created cells.

Please help me. Thanks.
Here is the code snippet :

```
    var input = $("<input type='text'>").appendTo(td);
    input.autocomplete({
        source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"],
        minLength: 3,
        select: function(event, ui ) {
            $( "<div>" ).text( "Selected: " + ui.item.value ).prependTo( "#log" );
            $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
        }
    });
    $('<div>').attr({ class: ["ui-widget"],  style : "margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial" }).appendTo(td);
    $('<div>').attr({ id:"log" ,class: "ui-widget-content",  style : "height: 75px; width: 250px; overflow: auto;" }).appendTo(td);
```

You can have a look at the demo here : [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rush2ashu/hmfpkdxh/)

Comment: I have updated the demo with a necessary change. Now I see that the selected value is appended to the first cell div tag. I want that to update in the respective td. Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everywhere you are using `id` to `prepend` and when you `prepend` it will prepend to first id! The ids in the html should be unique and when you clone duplicate ids will be created!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao How about using the find or closest function and find the div in the current cell where the cursor is at this momemt?

Comment: I would suggest to use `class` instead  of `id` which you clone and then take help of `find` or `closest`